# Probability of triangles in random graph

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, random-graphs

$G(n,p)$ - binomial random graph on $n$ vertexes and with constant probability $p$ of edges. In general, is there formula for calculating probability that graph has no triangles. I'm not intered at asymptotic equality of this probability, for this purpose more articles in web.